# Vector fields- differential topology

Tags: differential-topology

[image]
Can anybody please explain me the reason for last 6th line.
(The set of all vectors at all points...)

Answer (score 2):

$p\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and so is $v$, hence the pair $(p,v)$ can be seen as living in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\times\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ which is $\mathbb{R}^{2n+2}$.

Comment: Okie got it. Thanks.